# Erro ao usar Câmera no Android 7.1

Tags: android

estou com problemas em uma rotina para tirar fotos, rotina simples que no Android 4.1 a 6.0 não tem problema mais no 7 ao tentar tirar uma foto para o app, tentei de tudo há uma semana tentando, procurando por este problema em fóruns, mais to quase desistindo porque não vejo mais onde eu posso procurar e por isto ver se alguém já passou por este problema.

O Erro é este

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1387072 bytes at 
android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3781)                                                                           
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
```

o código para a foto é igual ao que encontramos em tutoriais

```
    private void takePicture() {
    Log.i(TAG, "takePicture()");
    FirebaseCrash.log(TAG + " takePicture()");

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {

        arquivoFoto = getOutputMediaFile();

        if (arquivoFoto != null) {
            //Uri fotoURI = Uri.fromFile(arquivoFoto);
            Uri fotoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
                    getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider",
                    arquivoFoto);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fotoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
        }
    }
    FirebaseCrash.log(TAG + " takePicture() - pickImage()");
    FirebaseCrash.log(TAG + " takePicture() - Fim");
}

private File getOutputMediaFile(){
    Log.i(TAG, "getOutputMediaFile()");

    String appName = Helper.getAppName(getActivity());

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), appName);
    Log.i(TAG, "getOutputMediaFile() - pasta " + mediaStorageDir.toString());

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            return null;
        }
    }

    String timeStamp = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    File imagem = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            timeStamp + ".jpg");
    mCurrentPhotoPath = imagem.getAbsolutePath();
    Log.i(TAG, "getOutputMediaFile() -  mCurrentPhotoPath: " + mCurrentPhotoPath);
    return imagem;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult()");

    FirebaseCrash.log(TAG + " onActivityResult()");

    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        salvarFoto();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro ocorria quando usava a câmera mais ele não estava ali, a partir do Android 7 eles começaram a olhar o bundle, então onde tinha onSaveInstanceState eu comentei tudo.

```
/*public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
   FirebaseCrash.log(TAG + ” onSaveInstanceState()“);

   outState.putSerializable(“listFotos”, (Serializable) fotos);
   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}*/
```

minha activity tinha vários fragments e em dois deles e o da foto eu guardava dados ali.
Apos comentar o código os problema de Crash, TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size.... não mais ocorreram.

Obrigado ao Igor Morais pela força.